# Print a document passing arguments to Process

Tags: c#, printing, process, processstartinfo

I'm working on sending documents to a specific printer, in this case the "Microsoft to PDF" one.

Everything work fine except that a prompt comes up asking for the folder where to save the pdf and its name.

```
Process printJob = new Process();
printJob.StartInfo.FileName = pathToFile;
printJob.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
printJob.StartInfo.Verb = "printto";
printJob.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
printJob.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
printJob.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + pdfPrinter + "\"";
printJob.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(destinationPath);
printJob.Start();
```

Is there a way to pass any paramenter to `printJob.StartInfo.Arguments` such destination path and filename and avoid the prompt?

Comment: This code isn't printing at all. It uses the Windows Shell to execute a UI verb registered by an application for some file types. The verb's arguments are forwarded to the application which means you need to know *which* application is used, what parameters are accepted and whether or not the `printto` registry entry can forward extra parameters

Comment: The way this works is explained in [Verbs and File Associations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/fa-verbs) in the Windows Shell Developer Guide. The [Context Menu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers) page explains that `PrintTo` is meant to handle drag&drop printing and accepts *two* parameters, the document path and the printer and calls the application with them. In the end though, printing is performed by the application itself

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos for the exhaustive explanation, and thanks for the edit. I guess I have to find out if the `Microsoft to PDF` printer accepts extra parameters, which parameters to pass in case it does. This OR find a way to export a documento to pdf. Any idea for that?

Comment: On the contrary, you need to realize that `PrintTo` is performed by *the application that handles that file*, not `Microsoft to PDF`. If you want to convert a Word document, it's *Word* that registers `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Printto\command` in the registry and runs `"C:\...\WINWORD.EXE" /j "%1" "%2"` with the file path and the printer name. If Word is missing there won't be any `PrintTo`. Since Word doesn't accept any extra parameters you can't pass anything else to it.

Comment: The printto is just calling a window dll.  You could just use DllImport to make the call but what you are doing is fine.  Here is a link of all the parameters : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shellexecuteinfoa

Comment: @jdweng it's calling an application command line or DLL. For Word, Excel etc, it's calling a command line. In the end, the OP needs to know *which* application is going to handle that file extension. Check `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Printto\command` for example

Comment: @Oiproks your actual problem is how to convert a file to PDF. Printing is the short-of-hackish way to do that. What kinds of files are you trying to convert? Wouldn't it be better to actually generate a PDF file or use a conversion program? The `Print to PDF` itself is optional and may not be enabled on the user's machine

Comment: NO, NO NO.  Most Net library functions that uses windows resources are just wrapper that actually call windows dll.  It is also true in Word and Excel.

Comment: @jdweng are you saying [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers) and registry are wrong?

Comment: Ok. I don't have Word installed in my computer. I have LibreOffice (I know it's disgusting, but that's what I'm working with) and the related key in the register is `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\soffice.StarWriterDocument.6\shell\printto\command`. I suppose it is using this one. Following the logic, i'll have to find another day to automate the pdf creation from xls files. Btw, thanks for the note. I've learnt something new.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What I was trying to accomplish was an automated conversion program. And yes, I went for the easy/hackish way. It didn't work. I'll find another way. I just don't want to use pay-per-use-libraries

Comment: I saying the shell is just a wrapper for the window dll and the shell may not be implementing all the options of the window d.  The shell does nothing but takes the parameter list and call the window dll.